# unable to docker push images in artifactory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, artifactory, nginx-ingress

I'm having problems pushing images to my docker repo in Artifactory.  Pulling the images works as expected, but pushing them gives me an error.  I can see the progress bar pushing the image, but somehow it times out w/ a "I/O Timeout"

My setup consists of an Artifactory instance running in my k8 cluster and I have a F5 in front of it for SSL offloading.  I followed [these instruction](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-artifactory-as-a-docker-registry-with-f5-and-https/) for using the repository path method.

On the http settings I've tried using the nginx/http reverse proxy or just using the embedded tomcat.  I either the the "I/O timeout" or a "503 Service Unavailable" (when using the embedded).

I know network wise everything is ok, since I can push other items. i.e, files, npm etc...  It's a bit frustrating that I'm able to pull but not push.  Has anyone seen this before??

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are using VPN or if your DNS settings are correct? I know you stated that network works fine but this might be our first suspects.

Answer (score 1):

Do the docker push command again with artifactory UI open ( Admin -> System logs -> Request log )

You should see a few requests coming in with '/api/docker' in the path. What's the return code and full path shows in request log?

Answer (score 0):

The docker registry push would require docker login. You may need to get credentials for the docker registry so that you push. Say if you have saved password in a file

`docker login --username=yourhubusername --email=youremail@company.com`

And then try push.

Comment: Thanks @sham332 but I’m able to login and pull images so it’s not an issue of credentials. I’m thinking it’s something in the settings..